# Send email to selected name from dropdown list

Tags: php, html, email

I have a form which sends email to the managers. I want to create a dropdown list of managers whom users can send their email to. I wanted to know if it's possible to change the value of $to based on the selected name from the dropdown list.

Here's my PHP code:

```html
<?php
if(!isset($_POST['submit']))
{
 //This page should not be accessed directly. Need to submit the form.
 echo "error; you need to submit the form!";
}
$name = $_POST['name'];
$visitor_email = $_POST['email'];
$message = $_POST['message'];

//Validate first
if(empty($name)||empty($visitor_email)) 
{
    echo "Name and email are mandatory!";
    exit;
}

if(IsInjected($visitor_email))
{
    echo "Bad email value!";
    exit;
}

$email_from = 'renzoandredg@gmail.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "New Form submission";
$email_body = "You have received a new message from the user $name.\n".
    "Here is the message:\n $message".
    
$to = "renzoandredg@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $visitor_email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: thank-you.html');


// Function to validate against any email injection attempts
function IsInjected($str)
{
  $injections = array('(\n+)',
              '(\r+)',
              '(\t+)',
              '(%0A+)',
              '(%0D+)',
              '(%08+)',
              '(%09+)'
              );
  $inject = join('|', $injections);
  $inject = "/$inject/i";
  if(preg_match($inject,$str))
    {
    return true;
  }
  else
    {
    return false;
  }
}
   
?>
```

**PS: Forget the form, I only want to know if my question is applicable.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. It's possible and it's pretty easy to implement.

In your HTML form, add these code:

```
<select name="emailTo">
    <option value="email1@yahoo.com">Email 1 </option>
    <option value="email2@gmail.com">Email w</option>
</select>
```

And your $to in the PHP file should be like this:

```
$to = $_POST['emailTo'];
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is not about PHP particularly.
Yes you can do that, you may use HTML datalist for autocompleting input.
https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp

There are also some better JS plugins for doing that.
Like this one: https://bootstrap-tagsinput.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/

on the php side use [explode](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to get rid of commas/spaces if you need to and get result as an array to form it as you want.

P.S.: Stackoverflow is not a development forum. You should search on google for fundamental questions.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, simple do $to = $_POST['email_from_drop_memu'];